# Running a shell script and then displaying contents of a file from PHP

Tags: php, linux, shell, ubuntu

I have a PHP page (located at: /var/www/) that has to run a shell script (located at: /home/anas/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/new_run.sh) and text file (located at: /home/anas/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/results/text.txt) that will be generated after script runs in about 10 to 15 seconds.

I want just to click the button from PHP and it runs the script and when the text file gets created in the respective directory, it should display on the PHP page.

Problem I am getting is that the text file is not being updated. It is same old that I created when executed shell script manually. (Output has to change.)

Either the script is not running or it is not creating text file. I can't figure out what to do now.

I have done this till now:

**final.php**

```html
<html>

<body>
  <?php
if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {
 echo shell_exec('sh /home/anas/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/new_run.sh');
sleep(15);
echo file_get_contents("/home/anas/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/results/text.txt");
  }
 ?>
    <form action="final.php" method="post">
      <input Name="Submit1" type="submit">
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is `new_run.sh` supposed to echo anything? Do you see that output on your webpage when the `shell_exec()` call runs?

Comment: Yes, it should echo. It is a long script. And no, I don't see any kind of output when shell_exec() call runs.

Comment: That means the script could not be executed (`shell_exec()` returns `null` if there's an error *or* if the script doesn't generate any output, in this case it's likely the former). What system user is PHP running as (`echo shell_exec('whoami');`) and if that user is not "anas", which **folder** permissions does `/home/anas` have?

Comment: `echo shell_exec('whoami');` returns `www-data` that doesn't seem right.

Comment: Actually, it does. That's the default user that most webservers (Apache, nginx) run as.  That user is probably not allowed to access /home/anas. Does the script work if you move it outside that folder? For testing, you could try moving the script to /tmp, which is accessible for everybody.

Comment: I made a `/tmp/script.sh` containing `whoami` but still the output is `www-data`

Comment: Well yes, that's not going to change. The solution to your problem is to create a situation where the `www-data` user is able to execute your script and write to the text file. So you either need to move your script out of `/home/anas`, or you need to change permissions to allow `www-data` to access the script (and every folder in the path to the script).

Answer (score 0):

based on my experimental results, it is due to **permission issues.**

I created two files:

**example.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 123
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
echo shell_exec("sh /path/to/stackoverflow/example.sh");
echo "done";
```

when the permission of `example.sh` is **777**, everything is ok.

when the permission of `example.sh` is **000**,

will output insufficient permissions in the terminal, and  **will output nothing in the browser.**

I noticed that you should be in a browser environment, so will output nothing and no errors

Comment: Changed the permission to 777 but still it doesn't work. Neither `echo shell_exec()` is echoing anything nor the `text.txt` is updated.